# WordPressで複数のプランがあるサブスク型のECサイトを作りたい

Tags: wordpress

#### 前提・実現したいこと

WordPressでサブスク型のECサイトを制作・運営しています。
サブスクリプションの決済はStripeを利用しています。
複数のプランがある有料会員と無料会員を分けたく、有料会員のみStripeでサブスクリプションの請求をしています。

#### 発生している問題

Stripeの継続課金機能と連携させやすかったSimple WP Membershipを用い会員機能を制作しているのですが、ユーザーがログインしてもログインしていないように挙動することがあります。
ユーザーがログインした際にメニューの表示などを切り替えるようにしているのですが、ログイン後のページ遷移などは正常なのですがメニューの表示は切り替わらずに注文ページへ進もうとすると再度ログインを求められ、ログインページからログインしてもまた同じ状況になってしまうという問題が発生します。
しかしこの問題は毎回ではなくたまに発生します。

#### 考えた原因

Stripeで有料プランをいくつか作っていてそのプランごとに注文数の上限などを設けたかったため、会員区分に応じた継続課金を実装しやすかったWP Full StripeとSimple WP Membershipを組み合わせて利用しています。
また有料会員と無料会員で表示させる内容を変えたかったため会員区分ごとに表示内容を変更しやすいUltimate Memberも使っています。ECカートの部分にはWooCommerceを使用しています。
ログイン機能に関わるプラグインを複数使っているため互いに干渉しているのではないかと推測しているのですが、どの機能も捨てがたくこれらを利用しながら不具合の起きないサイトを制作できればと考えております。
またCookieやキャッシュの可能性も考えましたが、原因はわかっていません。

#### 補足情報

ログインできない現象は毎回起きるわけはなくたまに起きます。起きた場合も、
・時間をおいて再度ログインしてみる
・ログイン後複数回ページ遷移してみる
などの方法でログインしたと認識されメニュー表示などが切り替わることが多いです。
毎回ログインできないようならプラグインの構成などを一から考え直したいのですが、たまに起きる問題のため、またもうすでにサービスとしてリリースしているのでサイトを一から構築し直すのが難しいため、現状の環境でこの問題が起きないようにできればと考えております。

考え方のヒントだけでも構いませんので、解決方法やアドバイスなどいただけましたら幸いでございます。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: sessionの保存先（session.save_path）を設定するとどうでしょう

Comment: yyzさま まだ完全には解決できていませんが、糸口が見えたように思います。ありがとうございます。